# Is it possible to enqueue the Youtube API script or does it have to be inline?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, api, youtube

The code below is the main part of a function in my functions.php which returns a `div` and `script` which ultimately output a youtube API iframe to the template where the code had been called from. At the moment it's working fine; however I would like to enqueue the javascript, or at least move it out of my PHP code. I tired moving it to my main JavaScript file ( which is enqueued in the footer ) but it doesn't work when I move it there. ***Edit***: I had hardcoded the vars to avoid having to use `wp_localize_script` so as to out of the picture.

Surely there's a better way ( or WordPress way ) of doing this?

```
$return = '

    <div id="' . $postid . 'player"></div>

    <script> var tag = document.createElement("script"); tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player("'. $postid .'player", {
            height: "315",
            width: "560",
            videoId: "'. $videoID .'",
        });
    }
    </script>

    ';

return $return;
```

Comment: Main script was already in the footer. Why would I need to  check the use of `wp_localize_script`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I know I will have to do that eventually. When I tested moving the script so that it was enqueued I had hardcoded these - will add that to my question.

Comment: tried putting it straight into header.php and things went pretty strange, couldn't figure it out

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", it is not really descriptive. What's the expected result and what do you get? Any JS errors in console?

Comment: Do you mean when I had it in the footer or the header? In the footer it literally produced no output whatsoever that I could detect ( though actually I'm no expert with firebug ) ... in the header I couldn't make head or tail of it at all because it put the iframe in a kind of odd place ( not replacing the div like it should but in a sibling element one level up )  ... anyway what I meant to say was that after 2 hours I was more or less giving up on getting this code enqueued and am going to leave it inline as it works fine, unless someone else wants to have a go. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure the YT api is [`enqueued()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and added to the footer.

```
function wp_enqueue_scripts__youtube_api() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'yt-player-api', 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api', array(), false, true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_scripts__youtube_api' );
```

Next, output your div somewhere on the page.

```
<div id="' . $postid . 'player"></div>
```

Then, hook into [`wp_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) and make sure you set the priority higher that `20`. By then the script should be rendered on the page and you can double check with [`wp_script_is()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is).

```
function wp_footer__youtube_api() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'yt-player-api', 'done' ) ) {
        $postid  = 123;
        $videoID = 123;
        ?>
        <script id="yt-player-api-ready" type="text/javascript">
            var player;
            function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player("<?php echo $postid; ?>player", {
                    height: "315",
                    width: "560",
                    videoId: "<?php echo $videoID ?>"
                });
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_footer__youtube_api', 20 );
```